Unable to execute Terraform after converting Service Connection to Workload Identity
In Azure DevOps, I recently converted the Service Connection to using WLID and now I'm getting the message:
Error: Backend configuration changed
A change in the backend configuration has been detected, which may require
migrating existing state.
I added the following to the backend
use_azuread_auth = true
use_oidc = true 

I also added use_oidc = true to the provider
Any thoughts on this?

could you share with us relevant part of your yaml pipeline/task you are using? Also your main.tf to see how it is configured

have you seen this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-devops-terraform-oidc-ci-cd/azure-devops-terraform-oidc-ci-cd/ ?

How do you set the backend block in your .tf file? I shared a demo in an answer below. you can try to update your configurations referencing this demo to see if the issue can be fixed. @ITPRO85

@BrightRan-MSFT How would your configuration differ if I used a User Managed Identity with Federated Workload ID (OIDC)?  I actually created another Service Connection and switched the configuration to use the SC that was configured with WLID?

@ITPRO85, I also created a new ARM service connection using a User Assigned Managed Identity with Workload Identity Federation. When using this new ARM service connection, the TerraformTaskV4@4 task also can work fine with the same configuration in the .tf file. See EDIT in my answer.

I set up a demo referencing the following documentations:

Azure Provider: Authenticating using a Service Principal with Open ID Connect
Backend: Azure AD Service Principal or User Assigned Managed Identity via OIDC (Workload Identity Federation)


The content of providers.tf file looks like below.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=4.6.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  use_oidc = true
  features {}
}

In the pipeline (azure-pipelines.yml), I use the pipeline tasks provided by the extension "Terraform" to run the related Terraform commands.
# azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: newACR
  displayName: 'Create ACR'
  steps:
  - task: TerraformInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Install Terraform'
  
  # The service connection 'myArmConnection_01'has the access to the backend Storage Account.
  # It has been converted to using workload identity federation.
  # So, the argument '-backend-config=use_oidc=true' will be automatically added to the 'terraform init' command.
  # The option "backendAzureRmUseEntraIdForAuthentication: true" will add
  # the argument '-backend-config=use_azuread_auth=true' to the 'terraform init' command.
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: 'Terraform init'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ACR'
      backendAzureRmUseEntraIdForAuthentication: true
      backendServiceArm: 'myArmConnection_01'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'myResourceGroup'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'mystorageaccount'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'mycontainer'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'tf/terraform.tfstate'

  # The service connection 'myArmConnection_02'has the access to the Azure Subscription
  # and Resource Group where the new Azure resoueces (ACR in this sample) need to be deployed to.
  # It also is using workload identity federation.
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: 'Terraform plan'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ACR'
      commandOptions: -out=main.tfplan
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'myArmConnection_02'

  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: 'Terraform apply'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ACR'
      commandOptions: main.tfplan
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'myArmConnection_02'

  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: 'Terraform output'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'output'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ACR'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'myArmConnection_02'

With above configuration, the TerraformTaskV4@4 task can work fine with the ARM service connections which are using workload identity federation. And on the step 'Terraform init', the task will run the command like as below.
terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=mystorageaccount -backend-config=container_name=mycontainer -backend-config=key=tf/terraform.tfstate -backend-config=resource_group_name=myResourceGroup -backend-config=subscription_id=xxxx -backend-config=tenant_id=xxxx -backend-config=use_azuread_auth=true -backend-config=client_id=*** -backend-config=oidc_token=*** -backend-config=use_oidc=true


EDIT:
I created a new ARM service connection using a User Assigned Managed Identity with Workload Identity Federation.

In above YAML sample, I just changed to use this new ARM service connection, no changes on other configurations, and also no changes in the .tf files.
When I run the TerraformTaskV4@4 task with the new ARM service connection, it also can work fine.


Thanks for your help. This was exactly what I needed. Drinks on me. :)
